# Guess the word: I/O C logic error

Tags: c, string, io, fgets

Quite a simple program:

```
int main (void)
    {
    int i = 0, length=0;
    char password[] = SECRET;
    char guess[10];

    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf( "Enter the password: " );
        fgets (guess, 10, stdin );
        length=strlen(guess);
        guess[length]='\0';
        if(strcmp( guess, password ) == 0 ){
          printf("\aYou got it right!\n" );
          return 0;
          }
          else printf("You wrote %s Incorrect guess\n\n", guess);
    }
    puts("Sorry, you're all out of guesses");

    return 0;

}
```

But it doesn't work.

Even in the bizarre situation where I can get the program to say:
"You guessed 'black'. Sorry, the password was 'black'"
Thought there might be some issue with some hidden character, blank space, garbage information or whatever throwing off the string comparison, but I can't seem to find what it is!

Comment: What  does "it doesn't work" mean? You've posted code that won't even compile (`char password[] = SECRET;` and no explanation of what the problem is you're trying to solve.

Comment: @KenWhite SECRET, as the block capitals suggests is a constant, which in this case is defined in preprocessor code. What the password is is not itself terribly relevant

Comment: @Duncan: And how are *we* (who don't have access to your personal knowledge of code not in the question) supposed to know that? (I could care less what the password is; hard-code in a value like `"password"`.) We can't see your screen from here, or read your mind; your question should contain actual, **compilable** code that demonstrates the problem, and a clear description of what that problem is, if you want help solving it. "it doesn't work" isn't a problem description; it's a statement meaning nothing until you explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: @KenWhite It's not too hard to make the code compilable. To get compilable code, the `#include` would have to be included as well as `#define SECRET`. Note the statement "doesn't work" _is_ explained in the very next paragraph.

Comment: @JanDvorak: No, to make the code compilable would require either a local `#define SECRET` or changing it to `char password[] = "SECRET";`, and as we have no idea of the experience level of the poster of this question (based on the simplicity of the code posted, it could be posted by someone working on a new class assignment), and making an assumption about what might or might not be `#defined` elsewhere (and whether CASE implies `#define`d or not) is wrong. As far as whether "doesn't work" was explained or not, I disagree with your assessment, but thank you for your opinion. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you learn to use the debugger, you would probably see that the string returned by `fgets()` includes the newline character, which doesn't match the string you compare to.

And what is the point of this code:

```
length=strlen(guess);
guess[length]='/0';
```

First of all, I can only assume you meant `\0` instead of `/0`. And second, `strlen()` works by locating the null terminator. So what's the point of finding the terminator and then writing a terminator at the same location?

Comment: I believe this is not the only problem. See the comment by @iccthedral

Comment: `guess[length-1] = '\0'` would solve it quickly, though `length`. should  be `>0`

Comment: Typo combined with wrong array position was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: And you have the problem if your password's length is `>9`. Be aware.

Comment: @iccthedral if you mean buffer overflow, doesn't the second argument to `fgets` take care of that (unless it's off-by-one)?

Comment: `strcmp(..) == 0` evaluates to false if his password length is `>9`.  It's all I meant.

Answer (score 1):

instead of making:

```
 length = strlen(guess);
 guess[length]='\0';
```

you should make this:

```
char *s = strchr(guess, '\n');
if (s) {  
    // new line is found  
    *s = 0;  
} else {  
    // user has exceeded max chars  
    guess[sizeof(guess) - 1] = 0;  
}
```

I advice you to use strncmp instead of strcmp to avoid buffer overflow attacks.